# Как легче хранить данные в базе данных?

Tags: база-данных, php, mysql

Потребовалось хранить в БД инфу о приватности юзеров и отдельных их разделов в виде чисел 1 или 2 или 3 ... , а также настройки сайта того же формата. В некоторых системах управления сайта видел, что хранятся они в базе каждая опция в отдельном поле. Возникает вопрос, а не накладно ли это? (для нагрузки или скорости выборки таких таблиц). Не лучше ли будет хранить в одном поле в виде "234132321" ? Соответственно и вытаскиваться будет только одно поле, а дальше разбираться с помощью "substr()", "explode()" и др. У кого какие мысли по поводу вышеизложенного?

Answer (score 6):

Есть такая наука [реляционная алгебра](http://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%E5%EB%FF%F6%E8%EE%ED%ED%E0%FF_%E0%EB%E3%E5%E1%F0%E0), на которой собственно говоря и основаны реляционные БД. Одним из следствий это великой науки является понятие [нормализации данных](http://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%CD%EE%F0%EC%E0%EB%FC%ED%E0%FF_%F4%EE%F0%EC%E0), которая придумана не для того, чтобы туманить мозги, а с вполне конкретной целью устранения избыточности и непротиворечивости данных

Так вот представление данных в вашем виде нормальной форме не соответствует и вообще не соответствует требованиям реляционности, а экономия о которой вы пишете это из раздела экономия на спичках.

В общем не советую - забивайте как целое поле - в конце-концов есть же короткие поля с типами `boolean, byte, short` и проч.

Comment: Если я правильно понял, нужно хранить такое одним числом (34232565, например) в одном поле а не в нескольких, и далее разбирать его по числам для дальнейшей работы? Я вот тоже склоняюсь к такому решению. Ну блин, некоторые системы управления сайта хранят в разных полях по одной циферки. Им лень разбирать одно число на составные числа или я что-то не понимаю?

Comment: @Garik Pokrovskij это скорее служит для "понятливости". Я вот как пойму, какая цифра за что отвечает?

Comment: @Garik вы поняли ровно с точностью до наоборот. Нельзя в одно поле пихать несколько свойств/значений!

Comment: Можно, но это будет не реляционная БД, а key-value. Со всеми вытекающими.

Answer (score 0):

Некоторые форумы (и не только) хранят часть настроек в базе в виде json. ИМХО тоже очень удобно...

*Смысл*: собрал данные в массив, запилил `json`, записал в базу. Надо прочитать -- вытащил из базы, преобразовал в массив с помощью `json_decode` -- получил легкий доступ до всех этих переменных.

Comment: http://php.net/manual/en/function.serialize.php не?

Comment: я привел пример (мысли, то что видел), можно и `serialize`, иожно и свою форму типа `var1=2|var2=3|var5=7`

Answer (score 0):

> Соответственно и вытаскиваться будет
> только одно поле, а дальше разбираться
> с помощью "substr()", "explode()" и
> др.

нагрузка на БД уменьшится, а сервер будет для каждого запроса обрабатывать строки , из-за чего скорее всего возрастет нагрузка.

Comment: экономия на спичках.

Comment: "Нагрузка на БД" точно не уменьшится. А при определенных выборках еще и возрастет в разы.

Comment: Дак всё таки, как же лучше делать? Каждую цифру хранить в отдельном поле или ещё как-то?

Comment: Хранить записи нужно в отдельных полях, либо использовать другие БД, MongoDB например. Если конечно речь идёт о повышении производительности и масштабировании.